# Foreign key without correspondence in the referenced table

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I'm trying to come up with a solution for an exercise in which I have to create 3 tables: one for employees, one for projects, and one for projects and employees, in which I have to insert the employee's ID and associate with a project ID. In the project_employee table, since it has only 2 columns that reference other tables, I thought I could set them bot as foreign keys, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE employee_project
(
    id_employee numeric FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES employee(id_employee),
    id_project numeric FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES project(id_project)
)
```

Then I stumbled upon a problem: when inserting values on the 3 tables, I noticed that one of the employee's ID number was 4, but on the table employee there was no line with ID 4. Of course, this line wasn't created, but I want to understand: is there a way I could create a line whose ID has no matching record in the referenced table? Could it be a possible mistake in the question, or is there something I'm missing? Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: The **whole point** of a foreign key is to **AVOID** this situation - make it impossible to reference a non-existing row in a referenced table ......

Comment: I suspect you want `int` not `numeric`

Comment: @Charlieface not really, it was the exercise's requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no rows in employee table with id_employee value 4 then there should not be rows in employee_project table with id_employee value 4. SQL Server will give you an error like below:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__employee__id__75F77EB0". The conflict occurred in database "test", table "dbo.employee", column 'id_employee'.
```

But if you want to create employee_project with composite primary key on both the column you can try this:

```
CREATE TABLE employee_project
(
    id_employee int not null,
    id_project int not null,
    primary key(id_employee,    id_project )
)
```

Comment: This was exactly what hapenned, but my exercise has a table with an ID that has no correspondent in the referenced table. I thought there could be something I was missing, since I can't create that line with the ID 4 in the employees_projects table

Comment: You wouldn't. It's foreign key's job to prevent you from doing such thing. Please check that database whether the relation exists there at all?

Comment: I thought so, I just thought it's strange that such record appeared in the exercise, hence why I thought I could be missing something. I thought there was this relation since the exercise says to create this employees_project table with 2 ID's and it sets both as primary keys. As far as I know, a table can't have 2 primary keys, so I thought it was the exercise's way to tell me they both were foreign keys, but now I can't insert a line with no matching record in the referenced table

Comment: But a table can have composite primary key. Those won't be foreign keys but primary key. I have revised my answer.

Comment: I see! I think this is what I was looking for, thank you so much!